# What happened to Sylar

Tags: heroes-reborn

Given that Sylar (Gabriel Grey) had Claire's power, he would have survived the hiatus. Is there any indication of his whereabouts or actions in Heroes Reborn?

Comment: http://www.slashfilm.com/zachary-quinto-wont-return-heroes-reborn/ Not an answer, just food for thought.

Comment: @Axelrod Thanks, perhaps they will mention him as they did Claire.

Comment: He has gone to "too expensive for TV casting" land, far across the oceans.

Comment: Maybe we'll see the top of his head under a sheet as well....

Comment: We all know that Sylar is Malina and Tommy's father. ;)

Comment: @Jonah Unfortunately, while it is a good suspicion, the writers are still leaving it open. For all we know we good see the back of his head as he leaves a room in the next 4 episodes.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, Sylar's exact status as of the events of *Heroes Reborn* is not known. We do know several things:

- Renautus still has information on Sylar, as evidenced in *Heroes Reborn*: "Dark Matters, Chapter 5". When Quentin Frady breaks in Renautus, "Sylar" is the name of one of the directories on their server.
- Noah is probably not still in contact with him, since in "The Needs of the Many," he mentions having known someone who collected people's abilities through their brains. If they were still in contact, he probably would say that he *knows* such an individual.

And...that's all I could find.

Comment: Last we saw, I believe Sylar and Peter ran away from the carnival together? And AFAIK we don't know what happened to either of them?

Comment: @Mike They were included in the "interim" tie in novel that explained about Clair getting pregnant (which showed that Sylar was not the father of her children). Sylar was never referred to during the television series.